# Arduino Uno & Wemos (0.66” Across) OLED Shield

Tags: arduino-uno

As I wrote in title, I have Arduino Uno and Wemos (0.66” Across) OLED Shield which i bought along wemos d1 mini.

For some reason I want to use it with uno. but there are just 0.96 tutorials internet and I don't know which pins to connect. I would appreciate any help.

PINS UNDER blue stick are

TX
RX
D1
D2
D3
so on..

[image: Wemos (0.66” Across) OLED Shield -- Driver IC: SSD1306 (I2C Address: 0x3C or 0x3D)]

Comment: how do you know i didn't?

Comment: were you this informative when you asked your first question?

Comment: I can find the code i have problem with connecting pins. i would appreciate if you help

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see when googling "0.66 lolin oled" is the link to https://wiki.wemos.cc/products:d1_mini_shields:oled_shield and their [Get started guide](https://wiki.wemos.cc/tutorials:shields:get_started_with_oled_shield). This yields the libraries to be used with it:

- for the OLED: https://github.com/mcauser/Adafruit_SSD1306/tree/esp8266-64x48 with the dedicated [test sketch](https://github.com/mcauser/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/esp8266-64x48/examples/ssd1306_64x48_i2c/ssd1306_64x48_i2c.ino)
- for the A & B buttons: https://github.com/wemos/LOLIN_OLED_I2C_Button_Library

Comment: thanks for the help man, but my problem is mainly connecting pins

Comment: You just stack it ontop of the D1 mini? what hardware are you working with? Also the included schematics (https://wiki.wemos.cc/_media/products:d1_mini_shields:sch_oled_v2.1.0.pdf) show you all the pins.

Comment: No, the thing is, I am not using it with D1 mini, i just bought it along that's it. right now, i need to use it with arduino uno.

Comment: The Uno is a 5V device and the OLED runs on 3.3V logic. You need a logic level shifter (for example this one https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) and then just conned the SCL and SDA pins to your Uno for the I2C connection (see schematics for which pin), plus power. I'm not sure if the library is Arduino-Uno compatible though, you'll have to find out and adapt it as necessary.